# Firebug fails to load js file

Tags: javascript, firebug

I've noticed that a syntax error in JS file sometimes causes that js file not to be listed in Script Firebug tab at all.

I'm pretty sure that Firebug is supposed to help finding such errors instead of excluding the entire js file.

What am I missing?

Thanks
v.

Firefox 3.6.13

Firebug 1.6.0

EDIT: 
Below's the example of the code that breaks it. The closing parenthesis was left on the $.each line, before instead after the function body. Now that I've experimented a bit, it appears to be somewhat inconsistent in behavior, but the bottom line is that the only error that gets reported is " is not defined", when another function defined in the erroneous file is called.

```
function aaa(){
    var sum = 0;
    $.each([1, 2, 3], function(i, val)){
        sum += val;
    };
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: What do you want to know?  If you don't post the particular code that you think causes Firebug to do something wrong, I doubt anybody will be able to help you.

Comment: I want to know if there is anything I can do to make Firebug report syntax errors in external JS files instead of just rejecting the entire file containing an error. I've found the error in the meanwhile, but my problem is with Firebug, not the code.

Comment: But OK. I'm editing the question.

Comment: What type of syntax error causes that to happen?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem and this is really annoying! For some reason because of a syntax problem firebox does not load the file. If i turn our firebug, the site and the script will load with errors. But it WILL load.

Comment: I had this issue today in Firebug 1.71b3 in Firefox 4. I eventually clicked on the Console and found the syntax error in my .js file, which was stated as `missing ; before statement`. The line it complained about was `Date now = new Date();` which in fact is not correct syntax for JavaScript (I guess my brain was in Java mode). I changed it to `var now = new Date();` and the error went away, letting my JavaScript file load in Firebug. Maybe the lesson here is not to depend too closely on what the console says the syntax error is, but just that there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. As people don't find this interesting, I can put in some hints. Hopefully they help someone:

1. Try reloading page twice to make sure that new version of external js file is loaded.
2. FF/FB have memory issues that most of us have experienced. Restarting FF could also help.

Comment: The sad thing was that a guy left an answer and got a vote down, so he was in rush to remove the answer and give me a vote down for the question. Really sad...

Answer (score 2):

I just found out, the same error i got was happening on the following line:

```
selectOptionNode.value = current);
```

it is a leftover parantheses which has no corresponding start parantheses. So this seems to be a reason for firebug to not load the whole script and never tell about it. Weird...

removing the paranthesis fixed the problem.

Comment: Did you try restarting FF? It was a while ago, but I think it made Firebug actually show the syntax error.